# If/else if on a text column in R

Tags: r

I'm a new to R and need help with the following.

| Have | Need |
| --- | --- |
| Male_18_24_pn | 18_24 |
| Male_25_39_pn | 25_39 |
| Male_40_64_pn | 40_64 |
| Male_65_84_pn | 65_84 |
| Male_85_plus_pn | 85_plus |
| Female_18_24_pn | 18_24 |

I need to create the "Need" column using the "Have" column, wondering how I can achieve this in R. As a initial effort, I tried the following code to test but got warning message and every cell of "Need" populated with "18_24":

```
if (str_detect(pe_1P_new$Have,"18_24")) {pe_1P_new$Need= "18_24"}
Warning message:
In if (str_detect(pe_1P_new$Have, "18_24")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into the `ifelse` *function* rather than the `if ... else` *construct*. Also, look into regular expressions -- which is the natural way to handle this.

Comment: For your next question please provide the example data in a machine readable format. Use `dput()` for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```r
require(data.table)

dt = data.table(
  have = c("Male_18_24_pn", "Male_25_39_pn",
           "Male_40_64_pn", "Male_65_84_pn",
           "Male_85_plus_pn", "Female_18_24_pn")
)

dt[ , need := gsub('(Male|Female)_(.+)(_pn)', '\\2', have) ]
```

Base R solution:

```r
dt$need = gsub('(Male|Female)_(.+)(_pn)', '\\2', dt$have)
```

No need for a loop or any conditional statements. You can extract the needed information with the help of a vectorized function, such as `gsub()` and a simple regex.

[Volunteer edit] This is an attempt to explain the regular expression logic of that substitution pattern (see `?regex` for a very terse but complete description). You need to understand what a capture class can do.

```
gsub('(Male|Female)#This matches "Male" or "Female", the first "capture classes" 
       _(.+)# Second capture class, matching anything after an underscore
       (_pn)',# ... up to but not including an "_pn"
       '\\2', # replace anything matched with only the second capture class
       dt$have)
```

You will not be able to run this version because the carriage retruns and spaces get in the way of the regex engine process.

Comment: Thanks It worked, don't know what the code is doing but I will try to google it and learn.

Comment: @Petax004 I tried to add some useful hints about what terms to search for in your google searching.

Comment: @IRTFM thanks for adding the explanations!

Answer (score 2):

We could use `trimws` as well

```
dt[, need := trimws(have, whitespace = '[[:alpha:]]+_|_[[:alpha:]]+')]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try `gsub` like below

```
> dt[, need := gsub(".*?_(.*)_.*", "\\1", have)][]
              have    need
1:   Male_18_24_pn   18_24
2:   Male_25_39_pn   25_39
3:   Male_40_64_pn   40_64
4:   Male_65_84_pn   65_84
5: Male_85_plus_pn 85_plus
6: Female_18_24_pn   18_24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package {unglue}

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Have = c("Male_18_24_pn", "Male_25_39_pn",
           "Male_40_64_pn", "Male_65_84_pn",
           "Male_85_plus_pn", "Female_18_24_pn")
)

library(unglue)
unglue_unnest(df, Have, "{}_{Need}_pn", remove = FALSE)
#>              Have    Need
#> 1   Male_18_24_pn   18_24
#> 2   Male_25_39_pn   25_39
#> 3   Male_40_64_pn   40_64
#> 4   Male_65_84_pn   65_84
#> 5 Male_85_plus_pn 85_plus
#> 6 Female_18_24_pn   18_24
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>